# Style an ID inside a class?

Tags: css

Good morning everyone,

I'm trying to give a dynamic href some styling through an id... 
lets say I want to use a background image for my "branding" id how do I hook into that?

Thanks. I know this might be obvious for some.

```
<div id="slides">
    <div class="slides-container">

        <div class="slide">
            <div class="hello">
                <div class="topper">Move</div>
                <div class="slab">your business forward</div></br>
                <div class="paint"><a href="">see how we make it happen</a></div>
                <img src="images/move.png"  width="1024" height="682" id="Intro">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
            <div class="caption">Branding</div>
            <div class="slideimage" id="Branding"><img src="images/surly.jpeg" width="1024" height="682" ></div>
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
            <div class="caption">Web/Mobile</div>
            <div class="slideimage"  id="Web/Mobile"><img src="images/shot.jpg"  width="1024" height="682"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
            <div class="caption">Labs</div>
            <div class="slideimage" id="Labs"><img src="images/affinity.jpeg" width="1024" height="685"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
            <div class="caption">FEATURE PROJECT _CUSTOM TYPE style</div>
            <div class="slideimage" id="featured"><img src="images/affinity.jpeg" width="1024" height="685"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: #branding {background-image:url(pathtoimagehere}; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:left top;}

Comment: [An alternative would be to use nth child selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925175/style-an-id-inside-a-class/17925297#17925297)

Answer (score 7):

All you have to do in CSS is add a background URL to your id. So it will look something like this:

```
 #Branding{

 background-image:url('images/surly.jpeg');

 }
```

Answer (score 4):

you will need this bit of css to accomplish this.

```
 #Branding{
     background: url("your image location");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.class #id
```

styles an ID inside a class. In this case, maybe:

```
.caption #Branding {
    ...
}
```

You could just use the id, however:

```
#Branding {
    ...
}
```

If you want more info about selectors try http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this in the header of your html page:

```
<style>
#branding
{
background-image:url('image.png');
background-color:#ababab;
}
</style>
```

Just use background-image if you only want a image
or you can use background-color for just a static color!

Answer (score 0):

Create an `id` and assign a style to it.

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="caption" id="branding">Branding</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
#branding{background-image:url(...); /* Your image path here */}
```

## EDIT:

An alternative way to do this would be to use `nth child` CSS selectors.

Here is the **[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MvfFx/)**

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="caption">Development</div>
<div class="caption">Labs</div>
<div class="caption">Branding</div>
<div class="caption">Designing</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.caption{background: url("existing image path");}
.caption:nth-child(3){background: url("new image path");}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

i don't think you can do it with CSS only. try using some javascript:

```
  document.getElementById('imageID').src = "SomeSrc";
```

Comment: It was about the background image of `branding` right, not about the src of the image. (I think. Question is really unclear)